# Group and sort results of array of structs in ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, structure, grouping

I have an array of structs in ColdFusion. I'd like to group the results by one element and sort it based on few other attributes of the structures. What's the most efficient and modern way to achieve this? I can change the sort order of the query if I need to.

For example now I have it first sorted by the title, to group by it, comparing the current loop title with the previous one and if it has changed I saw the new one.

```
myArray[1]
struct
Title = Heading 1
Description = lorem ipsum
Field 2 = this has to be second #1
Field 1 = this has to be first #1
Field 3 = this has to be third #1

myArray[2]
struct
Title = Heading 1
Field 3 = this has to be third #2
Field 1 = this has to be first #2
Description = dolor sit amet
Field 2 = this has to be second #2


myArray[3]
struct
Title = Heading 2
Description = onsectetur adipiscing elit.
Field 1 = this has to be first #3
Field 2 = this has to be second #3
Field 3 = this has to be third #3

myArray[3]
struct
Title = Heading 2
Description = Nullam ultrices
Field 1 = this has to be first #4
Field 2 = this has to be second #4
Field 3 = this has to be third #4
```

Must group and sort the results like the this:

````
Heading 1 = show ONE time because it is the title that I want to group the results
dolor sit amet  = sorted descriptions (this can be done from the SQL Query)
lorem ipsum  = sorted descriptions (this can be done from the SQL Query)
this has to be first #1 = sorted Fields (this can be done from the SQL Query)
this has to be second #1
this has to be third #1
this has to be first #2
this has to be second #2
this has to be third #2

--
Heading 2
onsectetur adipiscing elit.
Nullam ultrices
this has to be first #3 
this has to be second #3
this has to be third #3
this has to be first #4
this has to be second #4
this has to be third #4
```
````

```
  <cfif myArray[i].Title neq local.prevTitle>
    <h2>#Title#/h2>
  </cfif>
  <cfif myArray[i].Title neq local.prevTitle>
   <ul>
  </cfif>
    <li>#Description#</li>
    <li>#Field1#</li>
    <li>#Field2#</li>
    <li>#Field3#</li>
 <cfif i neq arrayLen(myArray) AND myArray[i+1].Title neq myArray[i].Title>
   </ul>
</cfif>
<cfif i eq arrayLen(myArray)>
   </ul>
</cfif>
<cfset prevTitle= myArray[i].Title />
```

I also need to add HTML elements before the grouping title and after the group of results. For example to show an `<hr>` before start showing the new grouped results. I've done few checks if there is another element in the array and if it's not the last one and the title has changed to show the HR. Something like this:

```
<cfif i neq arrayLen(myArray) AND myArray[i+1].Title neq myArray[i].Title>
     <hr />
</cfif>
```

But I was thinking that there must be a more efficient and modern way to do it.So if anyone's any suggestion I would love to read it.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? I would be tempted to load this into a query and run `.sort` on that.

Comment: Is this starting as a query object? If so, it would probably be much easier to set the query results how you need them in the original query itself. Can you provide a simple example of your database structure and data?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I've already set the sort order of the query in such way to get the titles in the correct order that will help me 'group' on it in the way I've 'demonstrated' in the sample code, but you are right maybe I could group those titles in the query somehow. If you have an example that can help me on this, it would be really nice.
(Coldfusion version 10)

Comment: @Shawn Yes this is what I was thinking from the start, if I could somehow get the results from the database in the correct order with the grouped title, but I'm still researching how can be done? If you have any example where you can group by one column and then you have all the other columns you need, please give an example.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of your database structure and data? And what flavor and version of DBMS?